# How to get req.body from multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

I need to get the req. body from the server before it uploading the file to multer.

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
   console.log(req.body) // null
   const folderName = req.body.folderName // null
    cb(null, `/tmp/my-uploads/${folderName}`)
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9)
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + uniqueSuffix)
  }
})

const upload = multer({ storage: storage })
```

How to get req.body

Comment: The file is in the body. You can't get the body without uploading the file.

Comment: Is there any solution for this?

Comment: No, there is no solution for the described problem, but maybe you should explain what you're trying to achieve and there could be a different approach.

Comment: I will get the upload folder name from the client request

Comment: You could send it in the header instead. Headers are available before the body is even sent. A common approach is to write the file into a temp folder and move it in a next step. How do you combine these two values (file and folder name)? I don't know if there is a format that allows partially reading a body. It could be possible with `multipart/form-data`, but I don't think `multer` supports it. You would have to write your own body parser.

Comment: I used header it works perfectly

Comment: Multer is parsing the multipart/form-data and returns only files.. Other way beside passing it in the headers will be to add the specific info as a param to the request url : ```localhost:8080/uploadfile?foldername=thenameofthefolder``` and to get the param: ```req.query.foldername```. so in the storage function you can write it like that: ```cb(null, `/tmp/my-uploads/${req.query.foldername}`)``` hopfully someone will find it helpful